# CSS before after charter size too small

Tags: css, pseudo-class

When adding menu separator slash with CSS before the slash is too small/cut in height.

Example code:

```
ul.menu.m-header-default-menu li.menu-item:before { content: "/"; padding: 0 .75em; }
ul.menu.m-header-default-menu li.menu-item:first-child:before { content: ""; padding: 0; }

ul.menu.m-header-default-menu li.menu-item {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

How to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. In this case, adding some HTML to go along with your CSS.

Comment: Here is the site in progress: re-design.se
You can see at the top right menu.
The separator slashes are small and align top.

Comment: Yeah, no, we need the code here on Stack Overflow. Otherwise, when people come to this question with a similar question, they can see what the solution is. When your site changes, the question won't make any sense. I urge you to click on the link I provided and read it.

Comment: Sorry I understand but is this related to the HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `font-size` of the `::before` content to 17 pixels. This would make its size match the text links.

Comment: Yes thats what I was thinking of. But how would that look like?

Comment: You would add `font-size: 17px;` to your `::before` styles. See this [screen capture](https://imgur.com/a/4FfCdkK) to review the change using Devtools.

Comment: Oh yeah but why and is this a solid solution? Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the "why", and yes, this should be an answer to your problem. You could use pixels or ems/rems for `font-size`.

Comment: I mean why does the separator get smaller than rest of the link text?

Comment: You would need to review your CSS/SCSS to see how the `font-size` is being set on various elements. If `<a>` has a font size set, but `<li>` and its `::before` pseudo class do not, this could lead to the differences in sizes.

Comment: Yes thats probably the case. I just got puzzled that even setting the <li> and ::before to same size the ::before still got smaller. Thanks!